# How to encrypt sqlite data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

For security purpose data wants to encrypt.
I want to encrypt sqlite data in swift.
How to perform this???
I read some solution that tell me use sqlcipher but get proper solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqlcipher is pretty much your only option if you want to completely and securely encrypt your database.

iOS has some built in functionality but these are easily circumventable.

There is a reasonable tutorial on the following link on how to prepare the encrypted db:

https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/ios-tutorial/

If you are wanting to use Core Data there are very limited options available to you. The following Github repo is pretty much the only usable solution for utilising a fully encrypted database within Core Data:

https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data

Comment: have you kind of link which give me whole steps from start to end done in swift @JordanMazurke

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged, please highlight the important elements of the links (code, etc) in your answer.

Comment: @JOrdan,  
For zetetic.net they charge for ios service upto ₹ 35,416.27  
  
and for second link Failed bank sqlcipher Library not present

Comment: @VivekGajbe zetetic.net do charge for commercial static libraries but there is nothing stopping you from compiling the libraries yourself. The link is actually to a tutorial for doing that very task. The second link is for a project that allows you to use SQLCipher in a CoreData context. Not really sure what you are getting at in your comment